# R help read_csv not working because of different formats of columns

Tags: r, import, import-from-excel

I am trying to import this dataset which is in csv (comma delimited) and i am not able to do it in r, i believe because the first column doesn't have quotes, month has quotes in every rows and so on..does anyone knows how can i import it?

Thanks

```
year,"month","temperature","precipitation"
1952,"Jan",-6,54.3
1952,"Feb",-2.8,67.6
1952,"Mar",3.7,55.5
1952,"Apr",11.1,37.1
1952,"May",12.8,75.6
1952,"Jun",16.7,101
1952,"Jul",19.3,81.9
```

Comment: Works for me. Whats your error message?

Comment: Works for me too. Both `read.csv` and `readr::read_csv` should handle this without any issues.

Comment: A possible alternative is to use `read.csv2` . In some cases it has helped me some formatting problems